# SQL Update: How to pass current value to function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, sql-update

I want to base64-encode all names in a table. (PostgreSql)

What does seem logical to me, doesn't work.

I tried:

```
update person
set name = encode(name, 'base64');
```

throws an error:
`ERROR: function encode(character varying, unknown) does not exist`

`SELECT encode('test, 'base64');`
-> works without problems

How can I pass the value of 'name' to the function?

Comment: Try to cast `name` to `text` and the result back to `varchar`: `encode(name::text, 'base64')::varchar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`encode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-CONVERSIONS) takes `bytea` as first argument. So you can use

```
encode(CAST (name AS bytea), 'base64')
```

Comment: Will he not need to cast it back to `varchar`? for the UPDATE to write back into the `name` column?

Comment: @Atmo No, the result of `encode` is of type `text`, which is "binary coercible" (= identical storage) to `character varying`.